# How to resolve 415 unsupported media type error in Jersey + AngularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest, jersey

I'm trying to read a Json (Text) file from my local machine and display it on web through Jersey & AngularJs.

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>Your REST end Point</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyRESTEndPoint</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>


        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.itc</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyRESTEndPoint</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller {

    @GET
    @Path("/receive")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject crunchifyREST(int a) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Value received from User is:   "+a);

        String string = "";
        InputStream crunchifyInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/abc.txt");
        InputStreamReader crunchifyReader = new           InputStreamReader(crunchifyInputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(crunchifyReader);

        String line;

        try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                string += line + "\n";
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       JSONObject jsonObject = null;
       try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
       } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
    }    
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('myController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.myFunc = function() {
    var d=$scope.num;
    $http.get('receive',d ).success(function(dataTable)                   
            {   
                $scope.result = dataTable;

            }).error(function(error)
                {
                console.log(error);
                  });
    }
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Task</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">      </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
            <form id="loginForm" class="form-group" >
                <input type=number data-ng-model="num">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-ng-click="myFunc()" >Submit</button>
                <h1>{{ result.name }}</h1>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have included the following jars-

```
asm-all-3.3.1
jersey-core-1.17.1
jersey-server-1.17.1
jersey-servlet-1.17.1
jersey-json-1.17.1
jersey-bundle-1.17.1
json-20090211
```

From HTML I'm just passing a dummy number as a parameter to $http. But I'm getting 415 unsupported media type. In debugging mode I can see that Json text file is been read from the system and it is not able to send that response.
Any help??

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense for a GET to have content, so it shouldn't consume anything.

Comment: @Zymus I put to test that since it is not working.

Comment: I think we'll need to see an example of the request in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `@Consumes` annotation is used to specify the `application/contentType` header of the POST requests where you send a Request Body, so you don't really need it in a GET request.

Secondly, it seems you're trying to use a Path parameter but you're not using the right syntax for that.

Try your Controller to be like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller {

    @GET
    @Path("/receive/{a}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject crunchifyREST(@PathParam("a") int a) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Value received from User is:   "+a);

        String string = "";
        InputStream crunchifyInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/abc.txt");
        InputStreamReader crunchifyReader = new           InputStreamReader(crunchifyInputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(crunchifyReader);

        String line;

        try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                string += line + "\n";
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       JSONObject jsonObject = null;
       try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
       } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a Query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Content-Type as application/json in request header. Your server is not understanding what your are requesting for ? Try below if it works.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
    app.controller('myController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

         $scope.myFunc = function() {
         var d=$scope.num;
         $http({
           url: 'receive', 
           method: 'GET', 
           data: d, 
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
          }).then(function (dataTable) {
             $scope.result = dataTable;
          }).error(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
          });
        }
    }]);
```